# Very slow async bulk import via RabbitMQ

Tags: magento2, api, indexer, rabbit-mq, bulk

I'm importing products using bulk Magento APIs and RabbitMQ. The problem is that the process is too slow and sometimes it seems that completely stucks.
Magento version is 2.4.2 and RabbitMQ version is 3.8.25

Following there are two screens of rabbitMQ queued messages and message rates in the last minute and in the last day

[image: rabbitmq-last-minute]

[image: rabbitmq-last-day]

As you can see it consumed almost 2K messages in more than 24 hours! There is something I am missing here.

I found out that Magento indexers were stuck with more than 10k in Backlog and the state was "idle" or "working".
So I changed the indexing mode to "Update on save" (realtime), then reset the indexers. In this way RabbitMQ seemed to have speed up a bit, but it still very very slow.
I also truncate the _cl tables from magento but nothing changed.

Comment: Any thoughts about speeding up it?

Comment: I didn't find out how to speed it up, but in that specific case the problem was that elasticsearch crashed and wasn't running! So you can check if elasticsearch is up and running if you're facing extreme slowness problems